# double to int and comparison

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I have a textfield and want to get the value stored as double and also compare whether it is between 2 and 20

```
double numOfYears = [[numOfYearsFld text] doubleValue];
```

Please let me know if the code above is correct and how can i compare/check between 2 and 20, since it is double ?

Comment: Just keep in mind that doubles cannot precisely represent every value, so if you've arrived at a double through calculations and it looks like a particular integer, it still might not be equal to that integer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, while your text field contains valid number your code to get its double value is OK (if field does not contain valid number your code will return 0).

Checking if your value is between 2 and 20 does not differ from what you would do in case you had integer (or any other plain number type):

```
if (numOfYears >= 2 && numOfYears <=20){
   // check passed
}
```

Comment: So you're saying the casting would be automatic ?

Comment: Yes, you can freely compare doubles and integers